# Pgfplot restricts x domain's to y's. Plot looks weird

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I am trying to plot a basic 2D graph of small floating point numbers (0:0.12) against a set of large intergers (100:100000) like so:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=100:100000,
    title={Request time dependence on database record size},
    xlabel={Database Size [number of records]},
    ylabel={Time [seconds per average of 1000 requests]},
    xmin=100, xmax=1000000,
    ymin=0, ymax=0.13,
    xtick={100, 1000, 10000, 100000},
    ytick={0,0.0001,0.001,0.01, 0.1},
    legend pos=north west,
    grid style=dashed,
    restrict y to domain=0:1
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (100,0.0004)(1000,0.002519528)(10000,0.0134010380006657)(100000,0.125218412)
    };
    \legend{CuSO$_4\cdot$5H$_2$O}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However the graph looks off (ignore the legend):
[image]

Any ideas on how to get X axis to actually have the required values ? (100, 1000, 10000, 100000)

Thanks

Comment: You've set `xmax=1e6`, but your highest x-value is `1e5`, mind the zeros. But you probably want `xmode=log` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of just changing the x-axis to log mode (as suggested by Torbjørn T. in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365732/pgfplot-restricts-x-domains-to-ys-plot-looks-weird#comment901271_365732)) I would suggest to use log mode for both axis. In addition to that you have some options in, that prevents the graph from showing up, why I commented them.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
%        domain=100:100000,
        title={Request time dependence on database record size},
        xlabel={Database Size [number of records]},
        ylabel={Time [seconds per average of 1000 requests]},
        xmin=100, xmax=1000000,
        ymin=0, ymax=0.13,
%        xtick={100, 1000, 10000, 100000},
%        ytick={0,0.0001,0.001,0.01, 0.1},
        legend pos=north west,
%        grid style=dashed,
%        restrict y to domain=0:1,
    ]
        \addplot[
            color=blue,
            mark=square,
        ] coordinates {
            (100,0.0004)
            (1000,0.002519528)
            (10000,0.0134010380006657)
            (100000,0.125218412)
        };
        \legend{CuSO$_4\cdot$5H$_2$O}
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Perfect. Just what I was looking for !